# Anylogic: Directing different products to different rack systems

Tags: anylogic

I am currently modelling a warehouse in Anylogic. I have a source that produces products of type 1 and 2 specified within the product agent as a parameter "type". I have pallet racks that have been divided into rackSystem1 and rackSystem2 in order to store the different products "type 1" and "type 2" respectively.

My challenge is to store the different products in the respective rack system using the rack store block. I have tried using the logic:

if (agent.type == 1) 
    rackSystem1

This has not worked out for me.

Please help, i am still learning Anylogic.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
agent.type==1 ? rackSystem1 : rackSystem2
```

[image: rackstore]

these operators are equivalent to:

```
if(agent.type==1) 
   return rackSystem1;
else
   return rackSystem2;
```